# How to show co-ordinates of some points on `imagesc` plot in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, coordinates

I have a 50x50 matrix which I am using to plot `imagesc` plot. I want to be able to show say 5 co-ordinate location on that imagesc with dark circles which mark the location of the wells. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I would check what rot90() returns for imagesc to work on. Perhaps it pads the image some how when doing the rotation.

Comment: @Vidar: Removing `rot90()` just to check doesn't do anything on the final matrix size in `imagesc` plot. Actually, if I do not use `plot()` which I am doing here to plot the circles then I get the correct `50x50` matrix on `imagesc` plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply setting the axes limits to the desired values after all plotting is complete:

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

In your case, `xmin` and `ymin` would be `0`, and `xmax` and `ymax` would be `size(mat_name,2)` and `size(mat_name,1)` respectively.

Comment: I found out before you posted. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
figure;    
imagesc(img);
hold on;
for i=1:numberofcircles
    plot(x(i), y(i), 'o');
end
hold off;
```

Comment: I did like this too, but it is somehow changing the grid size from `50x50` to `60x60`, even when there is no point lying outside 50. So, in that case the remaining grid area from 50 till 60 is empty and showing white color only.

Comment: Discretization. Like each cell is single grid.

Comment: I still don't understand. your image is 50x50, when you do imagesc, it should still be 50x50. Are you saying that the image changes it's size? Or are you talking about the window? Maybe try changing the size of the window?

Comment: only when I use `plot` with hold on to `imagesc`, then the size changes to `60x60`. I am talking about the total dimension of `imagesc` plot.

Comment: Can you check using the code lines provided in question to see if you get correct result? Thanks.

Comment: How come you are using imagesc, when you have 3 channels? what's the output of size(perm_5wells_matrix_NthModel(:,:,:,i)) ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, that's a typo: it should be`size(perm_5wells_matrix_NthModel(:,:,i))`

Comment: try: plot(y_wells,x_wells,'o');

Comment: Nope. It doesn't help either. FYI, `x_wells=[1,7,15,23,30]` and 
`y_wells=50-[40,30,45,10,43]`

Comment: how about: imagesc(1:50, 1:50, rot90(perm_5wells_matrix_NthModel(:,:,i)))